# Unable to properly align the text above the image

Tags: html, css

I'm unable to properly align the text tag inside the H1 above the image, everytime is out of the place where I want to. Sometimes it's in the left or right i tried to include the h1 inside the container but he just disappear.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="20; url=011.html" />

<title>title</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="shadow"<a target="none" href="paris.jpg">
<div id="texto"><h1>Yes</h1></div>
  <img src="010.jpg"  class="logo">
</div>
<video id="bgvideo" autoplay loop>
  <source src="club01.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/webm">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
#texto {
        top:198px;
        left:365px;
        width:62px;
        height:51px;
        color:white;
        position:absolute;
        text-align:center;
        background-color:black;
    }

    #texto h1 {
        margin:auto;
        line-height:51px;
        vertical-align:middle;
        color: #FFFFFF;
        font-size: 75px;
    }

    div.shadow {
        position:absolute;
        max-width:90%;
        max-height:90%;
        top:50%;
        left:50%;
        overflow:visible;
    }
    img.logo {
        position:relative;
        max-width:90%;
        max-height:90%;
        margin-top:-60%;
        margin-left:-50%;
        border-radius: 5%;
    }

    video#bgvideo{
    min-width:100%;
    min-height:100%;
    width:auto;
    height:auto;
    background-size:cover;
    }
```

Comment: You have a syntax error at `<div class="shadow"<a target="none" href="paris.jpg">` you need to close the `.shadow` div like this: `<div class="shadow">` missing **>**

Comment: I did, i still having the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried something like this?

```
<html>
    <head>
    <style>
        #texto {
            width:100%;
            height:51px;
            color:white;
            text-align:center;
        }

        #texto h1 {
            width: 60px;
            display: block;
            margin: 0 auto;
            line-height:51px;
            vertical-align:middle;
            color: #FFFFFF;
            text-align:center;
            background-color:black;
            font-size: 30px;
        }

        div.shadow {
            max-width:90%;
            text-align: center;
            max-height:90%;
            overflow:visible;
        }
        img.logo {

            max-width:90%;
            max-height:90%;       
            border-radius: 5%;
        }
        video#bgvideo{
            min-width:100%;
            min-height:100%;
            width:auto;
            height:auto;
            background-size:cover;
        }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="shadow">
            <a target="none" href="">
            <div id="texto"><h1>Yes</h1></div></a>
            <img src="http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/teenbeachmovie/images/b/bf/Sad-face.jpg"  class="logo">
        </div>
        <video id="bgvideo" autoplay loop>
            <source src="club01.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/webm">
            Your browser does not support the video tag.
        </video>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Fixed! Lacking of position:fixed; on the video. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I had to mess a little bit with the CSS to make it visible on the fiddle, but take a look at this:

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2p28u9y0/)

Basically, you just need to position both the image and the `h1` with absolute in relation to the `textto` div. Then you can do:

```
#texto h1 {
    margin:auto;
    line-height:51px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -100%);
    vertical-align:middle;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 75px;
}
```